# jquery mobile text input can't see text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phonegap jQuery Mobile text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767506/phonegap-jquery-mobile-text-input)

I'm pretty knew to jQuery mobile... I'm having and issue with text inputs and search inputs. When I click inside the text field, or have the text field focused, then type, no text comes up at all. Just stays white and blank. Here is a little snippet of the code. Let me know if you see anything wrong with it. Thanks!

```
<div data-role="content">   
  <label for="basic">Text Input:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""  />
</div><!-- /content -->

        update:
```

works fine in firefox, not in chrome.

Comment: Check if your text-color is set same as the input field background color.This can be happen as the code seems okay !

Comment: it's really odd, the text color is set to black, there is just no text being entered...

Comment: actually my text input will focus but no cursor

Comment: posted a new thread related to phonegap and link to xcode project with code... this is really weird... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767506/phonegap-jquery-mobile-text-input

Comment: this is lame, i don't get why this is closed, it's a pretty legit question.

Comment: my other post got closed, so if it's a duplicate, the idea should be to close 1 of them, not both of them.