# Phonegap jQuery Mobile text input

Tags: jquery, html, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am hoping somebody might be able to tell me why my text input isn't working in my Phonegap project that is using jquery mobile. Here is a link to my XCode project in DropBox:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/49t41ixh72at9q5/yc8USE2Lun

The text field, when getting focus, does not allow text input. You will want to open the index.html in the www/ folder.

This is a Phonegap project, using jquery mobile, and xcode to run the ios simulator.

A sample of the code that is causing a problem is this:

```
<div data-role="content">   
  <label for="basic">Text Input:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""  />
</div><!-- /content -->
```

UPDATE: Solved!

check out the link below:

[Phonegap styles -webkit-user-select: none; disabling text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812587/phonegap-styles-webkit-user-select-none-disabling-text-field)

Comment: are you setting focus on that text field programmatically?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter nope, i am just clicking on it and trying to enter text.

Comment: @Armand yes i posted the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812587/phonegap-styles-webkit-user-select-none-disabling-text-field if you don't mind please upvote this and request it not be closed, it's a common problem.

Comment: i think it's totally ironic that it says below that this is "unlikely to help any future visitors". one thing that really annoys me about stackoverflow

Comment: @botbot, indeed. This question actually helped me, and OP helped me find the solution to the problem.